# how to do Json Parsing in android

Tags: java, android

```
http://localhost:8080/RESTfulProject/REST/WebService/GetFeeds
```

This is web Url

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Tom B","description":"4006","url":"www.Norway.com"},
{"id":2,"title":"Tom c","description":"4007","url":"www.NorwayC.com"},
 {"id":3,"title":"Tom D","description":"4008","url":"www.NorwayD.com"},
 {"id":4,"title":"TomE","description":"www.google.com","url":"url"}]
```

and this format of data i want parse and Print it Title in Listview But i am Unable to Parse it plz check where is the Problem. here is my code:

```
package com.example.andjsonparin;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static String url="http://localhost:8080/RESTfulProject/REST/WebService/GetFeeds";

    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "title";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "description";
    private static final String TAG_USER = "url";
    JSONArray user = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
         // Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + json);

      JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
       Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + json);
        //Parse the values as below.
       for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); ++i) {
              JSONObject mobj = json.getJSONObject(i);
              String  id = mobj.getString("id");
              String  title = mobj.getString("title");
              String url-mobj.getString("url");
            }
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Json Parser class:

```
package com.example.andjsonparin;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return json;

    }
}
```

when i Run this code then it throw NullPointException in Jsonparser class please tell me how i will do so that  i can Out i dont know where am doing mistake

Comment: refer to my this recent [anwser.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259205/how-to-store-jsonobject-result-into-beanclass-using-java-in-android/20259282?noredirect=1#comment30219702_20259282)

Comment: The stack trace of the exception tells you exactly where this exception is thrown. Read it. And if you can't understand it, post it.

Comment: HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           
Here  so that i am not getting   json = sb.toString();

Comment: @user2794306 Check out i have updated your code and try accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);  <<<
```

you are getting `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject` from webservice. so do following changes in `getJSONFromUrl` method :

**1.** Change method return type to `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject`

**2.** Create `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject` from webservice response string as:

```
JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(json);
```

also use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to avoid network operation on main UI Thread

Answer (score 0):

```
    JSONArray array=new JSONArray(jsonString_Returned_From_Server);
                    int len = array.length();
                    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                      String  id = obj.getString("id");
                      String  title = obj.getString("title");
etc...

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting the JSONArray in your response then you will have to parse your response using `JSONArray` not `JSONObject`

Try out as below:

```
      JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
      Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + json);
      //Parse the values as below.
       for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); ++i) {
                  JSONObject mobj = json.getJSONObject(i);
                  String  id = mobj.getString("id");
                  String  title = mobj.getString("title");
                  String url-mobj.getString("url");
                }
```

**EDITED:**

In Your parser class you just need to return the `String` instead of `JSONObject`. 
In your `JSONParser` class write your method as below:

```
public static String getJSONFromUrl(String p_url) {
    String m_response = null;
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpget = new HttpPost(PeakAboo.BaseUrl + p_url);
    HttpResponse response;

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpget);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in));
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            m_response = sb.toString();
            System.err.println("JSON Response--->" + m_response);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return m_response;
}
```

Here is your updated code of your activity.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
         // Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + json);

        user = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
       Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + user);
        //Parse the values as below.
       for(int i = 0; i < user.length(); ++i) {
              JSONObject mobj = user.getJSONObject(i);
              String  id = mobj.getString("id");
              String  title = mobj.getString("title");
              String url=mobj.getString("url");
            }
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: NO am not getting JSOn Erray plz check Jsonparser class

Comment: @user2794306 In your `JSONParser` class try to return the `String` instead of `JSONObject`. Check out your code i have updated.

Comment: please Edit Both code coz am new in android and try to Learn JSon Parsing

Comment: response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) what about this Line Httpsstatus.sc_ok?

Comment: Still same Error Buffer Error is coming am Unable to read content actully In Json parser class That Is Problem actully plz help me in this ?

Comment: @user2794306 Have you tried my code which i have provided in my answer for JSONParser ?

Comment: if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)  what about this line how i will define  HttpStatus.SC_OK this?

Comment: You do not have to define. It will checked automatically whether the result is ok or not. If you will get the result successfully then it will return the result else nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method like below,

```
public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            return json;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            return null;
        }

}
```

and replace `MainActivity` like below,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     new GetResponseData().execute();
}

class GetResponseData extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private ArrayList<String> titleList;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading",
                false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
            String json_response = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            if (json_response!=null) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json_response);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    titleList
                            .add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                }
                return true;
            }
            else 
                return false;


        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (dialog != null)
            dialog.dismiss();
        if(result)
        {
            //do your stuff with titleList
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Buffer Error is coming

Comment: Still same Error Buffer Error is coming  am Unable to read content actully In Json parser class That Is Problem actully plz help me in this ?

Comment: http://10.0.2.2:8080/RESTfulProject/REST/WebService/GetFeeds also change your url like this, refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680457/get-xml-from-a-php-webservice-url-using-android

Comment: Thats is the Problem i think cant we parse from localhost data ?

Comment: yeah you can do check the link which i give in above comment

Answer (score 0):

// Here is the code of how to Request API from android Code:

```
JsonObject response = WebAPIRequest.makeJsonObjHttpRequest(URLS.USER_REGISTRATION, "POST", params);
```

// Now accessing class

```
public static JSONObject makeJsonObjHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    String json = "";
    try {

        if (method == "POST") {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```